# Referencing Cell in Pandas DataFrame Raises "InvalidIndexError"

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to reference specific cells in a dataframe, but getting an error.  Code is:

```
puzzle = [[5, 3, 0, 0, 7, 0, 0, 0, 0],
          [6, 0, 0, 1, 9, 5, 0, 0, 0],
          [0, 9, 8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 6, 0],
          [8, 0, 0, 0, 6, 0, 0, 0, 3],
          [4, 0, 0, 8, 0, 3, 0, 0, 1],
          [7, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 6],
          [0, 6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 8, 0],
          [0, 0, 0, 4, 1, 9, 0, 0, 5],
          [0, 0, 0, 0, 8, 0, 0, 7, 9]]
puzzle_df = pd.DataFrame(puzzle)
print(f'Shape: {puzzle_df.shape}')
print(f'Dimensions: {puzzle_df.ndim}')
print(puzzle_df)
foo = puzzle_df[1,3]
```

When I run it,

```
Shape: (9, 9)
Dimensions: 2
   0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8
0  5  3  0  0  7  0  0  0  0
1  6  0  0  1  9  5  0  0  0
2  0  9  8  0  0  0  0  6  0
3  8  0  0  0  6  0  0  0  3
4  4  0  0  8  0  3  0  0  1
5  7  0  0  0  2  0  0  0  6
6  0  6  0  0  0  0  2  8  0
7  0  0  0  4  1  9  0  0  5
8  0  0  0  0  8  0  0  7  9
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2020.2.3\plugins\python-ce\helpers\pydev\pydevd.py", line 1483, in _exec
    pydev_imports.execfile(file, globals, locals)  # execute the script
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2020.2.3\plugins\python-ce\helpers\pydev\_pydev_imps\_pydev_execfile.py", line 18, in execfile
    exec(compile(contents+"\n", file, 'exec'), glob, loc)
  File "C:/Users/brfoster/PycharmProjects/sudoku-ml/main.py", line 198, in <module>
    print_hi('PyCharm')
  File "C:/Users/brfoster/PycharmProjects/sudoku-ml/main.py", line 32, in print_hi
    foo = puzzle_df[1,3]
  File "C:\Users\brfoster\venvs\sudoku-ml\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 3505, in __getitem__
    indexer = self.columns.get_loc(key)
  File "C:\Users\brfoster\venvs\sudoku-ml\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\range.py", line 388, in get_loc
    self._check_indexing_error(key)
  File "C:\Users\brfoster\venvs\sudoku-ml\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 5637, in _check_indexing_error
    raise InvalidIndexError(key)
pandas.errors.InvalidIndexError: (1, 3)
```

Why is this failing?  This should be a valid index for the DataFrame.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `loc`:

```
foo = puzzle_df.loc[1,3]
```

or eventually `at` for referencing a single cell:

```
foo = puzzle_df.at[1,3]
```

output: `1`

Note that if you had a numpy array, you could do:

```
a = puzzle_df.to_numpy()
foo = a[1,3]
# 1
```

You might need to think whether a numpy array might be more adapted to your use-case.